# Html/css positioning help

Tags: html, css, xhtml

[image]

How do I align yellow side by side with red while keeping the 'Skills' text underneath the grey?

What i've tried: using float:left with red but that pushes up the skills text aswell. I've tried using relative and absolute but they're confusing to me.

**HTML:** Key div id's: `profiletable` (grey), `profileleft`(red), `profileright` (yellow).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Starbuzz Coffee</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="allcontent">
            <div id="header">
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <h1>Jonny</h1>
                <div id="profiletable">
                    <div id="profileleft"><?php echo $gravatar ?></div>
                    <div id="profileright">
                        <strong>Name:</strong> <?php echo $member->getFirstName() . ' ' . $member->getLastName(); ?><br />
                    <strong>Name:</strong> <?php echo $member->getFirstName() ?><br />
                    </div>
                </div>



                <h1>Skills</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                    when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                    electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
                    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
                    versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="sidebar">
                <p class="beanheading">
                    sidebar
                </p>

            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                &copy; 2005, Jonny
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:** key id's at the very bottom

```
body { 
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    font-family:      Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:        small;
    margin:           0px;
}

#header {
    background-color: #675c47;
    margin:           10px;
    height:           108px;
}

#main {
    background:       #ffffff;
    font-size:        105%;
    padding:          15px;
    margin:           0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width:            510px;
    float:            left;
}

#sidebar {
    background:       #7DCFE7;
    font-size:        105%;
    padding:          15px;
    margin:           0px 0px 10px 540px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #675c47;
    color:            #efe5d0;
    text-align:       center;
    padding:          15px;
    margin:           10px;
    font-size:        90%;
    clear:            left;
}

h1 {
    font-size:        120%;
    color:            #954b4b;
}

.slogan { color: #954b4b; }

.beanheading {
    text-align:       center;
    line-height:      1.8em;
}

a:link {
    color:            #b76666;
    text-decoration:  none;
    border-bottom:    thin dotted #b76666;
}
a:visited {
    color:            #675c47;
    text-decoration:  none;
    border-bottom:    thin dotted #675c47;
}

#allcontent {
    width:            800px;
    padding-top:      5px;
    padding-bottom:   5px;
    background-color: #675c47;
    margin-left:      auto;
    margin-right:     auto;
}

#profiletable{
    width:           510px;
    background:      #eee;
}

#profileleft {
    background:       red;
    font-size:        105%;
    padding:          0px 10px 10px 0px;
    margin:           0px 10px 10px 0px;
    width:            128px;
}

#profileright {
    background:       yellow;
    font-size:        105%;
    padding:          0px 10px 10px 0px;
    margin:           0px 0px 10px 128px;
    width:            200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change the margin on `#profileright`
   to `margin:0px 0px 10px 10px;` [ you modify the last value for the margin for the left side of the element]
2. Add `float:left;` on `#profileleft`
   and on `#profileright`
3. Add in your css the following
   `.clear {clear:both};`
4. After the `#profileright` add `<div
   class="clear"></div>`

live example [fixed - I had position the clear div in wrong position]: http://jsbin.com/afonu3/2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are working fixed-width, you can always position using `top` and `left`.

But to have a more fluent layout, put

- `profileleft` as `float: left`,
- `profileright` as `float: left;
  clear: right`

and then your skills will fall under those (you can even add a `float: left`).

You might need a small closing element under profileright and skills (a `<br />` with `clear: both` should do)

Answer (score 1):

in your CSS set your red and yellow divs to have the following:

```
float: left;
display: inline-block;
```

Create a new style

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Put in any block element, I use a div, with the class='clear' after the yellow block and before your Skills header.

Answer (score 1):

Add a

```
float:right;
```

to #profileright

then clear it with `<br clear="all">` here:

```
<strong>Name:</strong> 
<?php echo $member->getFirstName() ?>
<br />
</div>
<br clear="all" />
</div>
```